# Can no longer boot with rEFIt and Grub on early 2006 MacBook Pro

Tags: 11.04, grub2, refit, dual-boot

I don't know what happened to cause this.

I have Snow Leopard, Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal and Windows XP SP3 on my early 2006 MacBook Pro.  It is a Core Duo unit, NOT Core 2 Duo, so it is 32-bit only - Model Identifier MacBookPro1,1.  I use [rEFIt 0.14](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) for my boot menu.

For some reason neither XP nor Ubuntu would boot anymore.  I'd just get a black screen with a rapidly flashing underscore in the top-left corner.

Having both those OSes failing to boot suggested a problem with the boot loader in my MBR.  The rEFIT partition tool verified that my MBR partitions were still synced with my GPT partitions, so I rewrote my MBR partition table with fdisk while booted from [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php):

```
# fdisk /dev/sda
```

(fdisk warns about the disk having a GPT.  I press on anyway.)

```
p
```

(Print the existing partition table to make sure it's OK.)

```
w
```

(Write the old partition table back to disk.  This also writes a new MBR boot loader.)

After this XP would boot but Ubuntu would not, with the same symptom.  Now I used update-grub while chrooted into Ubuntu from Parted Magic:

```
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# chroot /mnt
```

Chroot issues some warnings about not being able to identify some group IDs.  I don't know why that happens, or whether it is a problem.

At this point while I am still booted off of Parted Magic's kernel, I am running from Natty's filesystem.

```
# update-grub
```

Update-grub detects each of my operating systems then claims to complete successfully, but still won't boot.

I asked this same question over at [rEFIt's Sourceforge support forum](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3420475&group_id=161917&atid=821765) but there have been no replies yet.  I also Googled quite a bit, and see many who have the same black screen problem, but none of their situations seem quite like mine.

Thanks for any help you can give me. -- Don Quixote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I need to run grub-install rather than update-grub.

Some googling around for documentation yielded the insight that update-grub just writes a new configuration file.  What I've been trying to do is to put a new boot loader into the beginning of my Ubuntu partition.

I have the following partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 EFI FAt (Empty; required by UEFI Spec)
/dev/sda2 HFS+ Mac OS X Snow Leopard
/dev/sda3 ext4 Ubuntu 11.04 
/dev/sda4 NTFS Windows XP
```

The following would run to completion and report success when I booted from the Parted Magic Live CD:

```
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
# chroot /mnt
# /usr/sbin/update-grub /dev/sda3     ### THIS IS INCORRECT
```

The correct command seems at first to be:

```
# /usr/sbin/grub-install /dev/sda3
```

However, grub warns about installing onto a partition with blocklists, which it does not want to do.  I give it the "--force" option:

```
# /usr/sbin/grub-install --force /dev/sda3
```

After this, Ubuntu 11.04 boots just fine; I am running it now.

[GNU Grub Manual 1.99](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)

[Installing Grub Using grub-install](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall)

Comment: Immediately after offering the bounty I managed to answer my own question.  Can I either undo the bounty, or award it to myself?

Comment: not normally (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) - however flag the answer and ask the moderators.