# linux image broken in grub menu

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have ubuntu 11.10.

In my grub menu, I have following images:

linux 3.*

linux 2.*

linux 2.*

My linux 3.* image is broken (if I try to boot from first image, i.e. linux 3.*, I get my caps and scroll lights blinking, and nothing appears on my screen).

If I boot from my second image, everything works just fine. My update manager shows everything updated. My software sources are updated. How do I fix my grub loader.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if grub is working just fine (you can boot an older kernel) but that you are having a problem with the new kernel (rather then grub).

For this I would file a bug report against the new kernel, but you will need to provide the error message you are getting.

See - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs

Comment: There is no error message I am getting...I just boot into it and nothing happens...even the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in one of two places, the loader or the Linux kernel. Although, it's seems to be more likely to be a kernel problem, I seem to have solved the problem with the following:

```
sudo update grub
```

Or else, something to the order of the following (taken from [Can no longer boot with rEFIt and Grub on early 2006 MacBook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64771/can-no-longer-boot-with-refit-and-grub-on-early-2006-macbook-pro)) might help:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-install --force /dev/sda3
```

And there's always the [grub manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall).

The best,